# copy in scrlttr2 causes problems

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

Since several days the option `copy` in `scrlttr2`, even in the MWE, causes the error

> ./samplefile.tex:139: Undefined control sequence.
> \iterate ...arker }\AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout
> \box \AtBeginShipoutBox \r...
>
> l.139 \end{document}

If I enrich the letter (remove the `%` in the MWE), I get into real trouble: It inserts an empty page after the page(s) of the original letter, the copy-page is moved to the right, the `scrheadings` are written over the header of the first page. With my MWE, I can only reproduce the error message and the overwritten header of the first page, but that's OK, because I'm quite sure that the error which causes the shift to the right and so on, is the same, namely `\AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout  \box \AtBeginShipoutBox`

```
% -*- mode: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\documentclass[copy
               % ,fromrule=aftername,fromalign=right,
               ]{scrlttr2}
% \PassOptionsToPackage{num,ngerman}{isodate}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
% \usepackage{calc}
% \usepackage{isodate}
% \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% \makeatletter
% \lohead{Ich Selbst}
% \rohead{\printdate{2020-10-19}}
% \pagestyle{scrheadings}
% \makeatother
% \setkomavar{fromname}{Ich Selbst}
% \setkomavar{fromaddress}{\parbox[t]{\widthof{Sample~Street~123}}{Sample Street 123\\12345 Stadt}}
% \setkomavar{date}{\printdate{2020-10-19}}
% \setkomavar{place}{Stadt}
\setkomavar{signature}{}

\begin{letter}{Herbie\\
               Herbie Stadt}
  \opening{Lieber Herbie,}
  bla
  \closing{Viele Grüße}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: copy.lco needs clearly an update. It shouldn't load etex, and it should adapt to the new latex hook management. Notify the author (the address is in the file).

Comment: A new corrected version is on the way to CTAN.